# cakephp 2.x not sending javascript generated fields info

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I am upgrading one application from 1.3.15 to 2.3.8. I generate hidden fields automatically:

```
function add_ingredient(ingredient_id) {
  $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        id: 'ingredient-' + ingredient_id,
        value: ingredient_id,
        name: 'data[Comanda][ing_changed][]'

    }).appendTo('#frm-ingredients');
}
```

and the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="frm-ingredients">
   <input id="ingredient-5" name="data[Comanda][ing_changed][]" value="5" type="hidden">
   <input name="data[Comanda][ing_changed][]" value="19" id="ingredient-19" type="hidden">
   <input name="data[Comanda][ing_changed][]" value="17" id="ingredient-17" type="hidden">
</div>
```

When I print $this->data->request in my  controller, the info is not there. Any ideas?

Comment: is `$this->data->request` a typo or you actually tried with that variable?

Comment: Should be `$this->request->data` indeed.

Comment: Without further information - it sounds like a js error. is what you're submitting in `$_POST`/`$this->request->data`? If so, show it.